# How to update data for logged-in users by using modelviewset in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer, django-generic-views

I try to operate the create method when generating the data for the first time and the update method if the data already exists after identifying the data of the currently logged-in user. So I wrote the code as follows but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

views.py

```
class arduinoViewSet (ModelViewSet) :
    serializer_class = arduinoSerializers
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset (self) :
        queryset = arduino.objects.filter(name=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def perform_create (self, serializer) :
        serializer.save(name=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data['name']
        instance.save()
```

serializers.py

```
class arduinoSerializers (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    name = serializers.CharField(source='name.username', read_only=True)
    class Meta :
        model = arduino
        fields = ['pk', 'name', 'temp', 'humi']
```

How do I write code to implement it the way I want?

Comment: "but it doesn't work the way I want it to" also include the behavior you're expecting from the code you implemented.

Comment: what could I do ?

Comment: Use Put method instead of Post for updating data in POSTMAN

Comment: @shoaibkhan you can do this in postman. But how can we do it in browser or app, we will need an url for it

Comment: @Aakash it is also possible in browser or app first you have to register your class view in urls